Dedicatory verse of the Mūlamadhyamakakārikā?
I am writing an essay on SN 12.15 (interested folks can read the first draft here; using a new laptop & don't know how to format the Word document to fit the PDF conversion) and was heaping praise on Mūlamadhyamakakārikā Chapter 15 however later came across the Dedicatory verse of the Mūlamadhyamakakārikā, as follows:

anirodham anutpādam anucchedam aśāśvatam | anekārtham anānārtham
anāgamam anirgamam || yaḥ pratītyasamutpādaṃ prapañcopaśamaṃ śivam |
deśayāmāsa saṃbuddhas taṃ vande vadatāṃ varam ||
I salute the Fully Enlightened One, the best of orators, who taught
the doctrine of dependent origination, according to which there is
neither cessation nor origination, neither annihilation nor the
eternal, neither singularity nor plurality, neither the coming nor the
going [of any dharma, for the purpose of nirvāṇa characterized by] the
auspicious cessation of hypostatization.

I am supposed to accept this dedication literally? What is this supposed to mean, where the Buddha taught dependent origination to which there is no origination?

Maybe the same topic ("dedicatory verses in the MMK"): How to reconcile emptiness with dependent origination?

Here are my notes:
Pratī - To go back to, return; etc. ;
Itihāsa - history;
samutpaad - equivalent ;
samutpaad - arising;
Utpādana - product;
Pratityasamutpada - imo ‘return to the origin of co-arising’;
Anirodha - unstoppable;
anutpādam - unproduced;
anucchedam -  unanihilated;
aśāśvatam - indestructible *Śāśvata - eternal;
anekārtham - multiple meaning - plurality ;
anānārtham - without non-sense (identity)?;
anāgamam - neither come or go?;
anirgamam -Anirgamama - inexhaustible   ;
deśayāmāsa - dark country?;
prapañcopaśamaṃ - negation of all phenomena?;
śivam -  auspicious, all that is good;

The teachings of the Buddha, here the teachings on dependent origination, mean that "Because this exists, that exists" to put it most simply. These teachings counter the views that things exist independently.
In the translation that you have quoted cessation is opposed to origination- a better translation here would be arising (not origination).
Because there is no independent cessation, annihilation, singularity and coming, there is no arising, eternality, plurality and going existing independently. None of these things exist by themselves. For the people who think these are independently existing (objectively existing) realities, the dependent origination (and emptiness) dispels those arguments. There is cessation only because there is arising. Likewise, there is arising only because there is cessation. These pairs don't exist by themselves- they exist only in dependence upon their opposite. This is the illusory like nature of reality.

Thank you for your answer but the viewpoint expressed does not sound necessary for Nibbana. All that appears necessary for Nibbana is the cessation of the defilements. That cessation occurs because there is arising sounds irrelevant to me.

Also, in the Pali, nirodha is like a synonym for Nibbana. When Ud 8.1 describes Nibbana as no arising and no passing away, the word for "passing away" is the common word "cuti" rather than "nirodha". The Pali says "bhava-nirodha is Nibbana".

If there is no arising of defilements, there wont be a cessation of defilements. Because there are defilements, they can be removed. You yourself mention in your 2nd comment- "In Nibbana there is no arising and no passing away". When not in Nibbana, there is both arising and passing away. But of course, we are masters of what is relevant to us and what is not- even from the great ocean of teachings of Buddha.
